# Is there a way to set my root password permanently in MySQL via command line without "mysql -u root -p" every time?

Tags: mysql

I succesfully installed MySQL on my new Mac. I setted my bash_profile file and everything's fine.

When I run "mysql -u root -p" in the command line, I type my root password and I can access MySQL Monitor without problems.

I was wondering, is there a way to set my password once and for all.

Every time I restart MySQL Server or reboot my computer, I keep getting "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'francesco'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".

And then I have to type "mysql -u root -p" and type my password again.

Thanks

Comment: What is accessing your mysql database on reboot? normally this should not happen

Comment: Nothing, I probably wrote in a bad english.

I'm just asking: I have to type my password every single time I want to use MySQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? Specifically the .my.cnf portion https://stackoverflow.com/a/13814461/447958

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked with the config file